# SOCAT / MINICOM "No such device or address"

Tags: ethernet, serial-port, minicom, socat

I've done quite a lot of research on Socat and I simply cannot create a device that Minicom can see.

In this case, port 10001 is the port that a Black Box Ethernet to Serial server is configured on.

My attempt thus far, one of many, now includes:

```
pi@rpi2 /dev $ sudo mknod -m 660 /dev/VCOM1 c 4 64
pi@rpi2 /dev $ sudo chown root.dialout /dev/VCOM1
pi@rpi2 /dev $ id -nG pi
pi dialout
pi@rpi2 /dev $ ls -la /dev/VCOM1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Nov 16 11:32 /dev/VCOM1
pi@rpi2 /dev $ sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:10001 /dev/VCOM1,raw
pi@rpi2 /dev $ sudo minicom
minicom: cannot open /dev/VCOM1: No such device or address
```

Picomon returns the same error:

```
FATAL: cannot open /dev/VCOM1: No such device or address
```

Comment: What's the end game here? What are you ultimately trying to do here?

Comment: I have a couple of Black Box ethernet to serial adaptors/servers connected to legacy RS232 capable devices and I 'simply' want to talk to them via Minicom. The serial server is sending RS232 comms out on ethernet via port 10001.

Comment: After some more testing etc etc this appears to work: socat pty,link=/dev/virtS0,raw tcp:192.168.15.15:10001 ,however I need to do some more testing.

Comment: This is my final command at this stage: `sudo socat pty,link=/dev/virtS0,raw,escape=0x0f tcp:192.168.15.15:10001`

Comment: If this ends up working for you, you can self answer your own Q's.